# The "beforeinstallprompt" event doesn't fire on Xiaomi A2 and so doesn't install my PWA

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, xiaomi, android-go

I am relatively new to this topic "PWA". I have developed a website and wanted to make it available as a PWA. On Windows and actually all Android phones I had in hand everything works, but on a Xiaomi A2 it just does not work. I couldn't test it on other Xiaomi devices unfortunately.
**The "beforeinstallprompt" event is not fired**. I can't explain it because on all other devices it is fired.
The Xiaomi A2 has Android 13 Go installed and Chrome 117.0.5938.153 (the latest version I can install).
Nothing can actually be wrong in the config, since it works on other devices, right?

And sorry for my bad English, I'm still learning it

I have already tried on a Pixel 7a, Samsung Galaxy A52 and also a Huawei, there I could install the PWA without any problems. On Windows everything works as well. Only on the Xiaomi A2 it does not install, I can not speak for other Xiaomi devices because I only have these.